# Capture standard output of another command-line program, with characters not in current codepage

Tags: .net, redirect, process, character-encoding, stdout

I'm using .NET `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` and `Process.BeginOutputReadLine` to capture the standard output of another program (specifically, [youtube-dl.exe](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl)) and save them into a string variable.

However the result variable contains only usual characters of my language such as traditional Chinese and English letters; characters such as Korean or Latin letters with accents simply vanished.

I `File.WriteAllText`-ed the result variable and checked the file using serveral text editors, so I'm sure they're lost, not that they exist and merely be un-display-able by console window.

Plainly executing youtube-dl in Windows Command Prompt displays complete messages including these foreign characters.

My `youtubeDL_process.OutputDataReceived` is simply:

```
(s, e) => {
  if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data)) this._filename = e.Data;
}
```

How to make the redirected standard output string with foreign characters complete, just like one directly generated in a command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You are directly saving the output directly to a file. Try this

```
youtubeDL_process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => CaptureOutput(e.Data);
youtubeDL_process.Start();
youtubeDL_process.BeginOutputReadLine();


private void CaptureOutput(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n" + s);
    //write fileChunks here using a StreamWriter.... 
}
```

//since CaptureOutput is receiving  your data  as string, experiment with other type (.e.g binary) so as not to strip out special characters (foreign characters) in the string, also check some UTF8 encoding or any other encoding  method  documentation.